# Splitting and Adding String in Powershell

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, split, addition

I have following issue:

I have a string, like `$word ='ABC.DEF.GHI'`

I want to split this String into an array at the dot and add a string instead. Desired outcome would be like:

```
$arrayWordSplitted = 'ABC 123; DEF 123; GHI 123'
```

with `$arrayWordSplitted[0] = 'ABC 123'`

I tried the .split()- Method but I can't add for every element with this.

I tried something like this:`$wordSplitted = $word.split('.') + '123'`

But I get `$wordSplitted='ABC; DEF; GHI; 123`

How to split and add for all elements in powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for that :

```
$wordSplitted=$word.split('.') | %{ $_ += ' 123' ; $_ }
```

Some  details: `$word.split('.')` produces a string array with words, string array that we pass through a pipe (`|`) to an elements iterator ( `%{ }`). In this iterator, we add to the string element (`$_`) the string `' 123'` and then send it back as an output with `; $_`. Thus, PowerShell build an *array of strings* with all strings suffixed with `' 123'` and stores it in `$wordSplitted`.

**EDIT:** You can reduce it like @Olaf has done it with :

```
$wordSplitted=$word.split('.') | %{ $_ + ' 123' }
```

Answer (score 1):

A little more verbose version would be something like this:

```
$word = 'ABC.DEF.GHI' 
$SplittedWord = $word -split '\.'
$AddedStrings = $SplittedWord | ForEach-Object {$_ + ' 123'}
```

If you want to re-join them ...

```
$arrayWordSplitted = $AddedStrings -join '; '
```

And the output would be:

```
ABC 123; DEF 123; GHI 123
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Really appreciate it! It works for me